# CSS bring two different font sizes in one line

Tags: html, css

How do I both bring the "July" and the "2016" in the line, with the font-size differences and the "2016" being aligned right?

```html
<div style="position: relative; width: 10%">
  <span style="font-size: 14px">July</span><span style="font-size: 20px; right: 0; position: absolute;">2016</span>
  <hr style="margin-top: 5px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Replace `<span style="font-size: 14px">` with `<span style="font-size: 20px">`

Comment: the author is not talking about the font-size @PraveenKumar

Comment: @PaulLemarchand That was a sarcastic *comment* only. One person has answered it. Please comment on n00b's answer.

Comment: Frankly, we don't know what he means. This needs confirmation from the asker about what "same height" means. (Align top, align bottom, align centre, same size... could mean a whole load of things at the moment)

Comment: I mean by "same height" that both texts should be on one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove:

```
position: absolute;
top:0;
```

Replace it by:

```
float: right;
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1L7Layk)

**HTML**

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 25%">
  <span style="font-size: 14px">July</span><span style="font-size: 20px;float:right;">2016</span>
  <hr style="margin-top: 5px;">
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I asked for - the July is still higher than the 2016 and I want it to be the same height

Comment: Since you already know the font-sizes you can move the small one a bit by giving it position: relative and top: 3px (=half of the difference in font size between the fonts in the spans). https://jsfiddle.net/j1L7Layk/2/

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean they should be aligned the same way? You can use vertical-align: bottom to get them aligned on the line, or middle to align them centered with each other.

```html
<div style="position: relative;display:inline-block;">
  <span style="font-size: 14px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:bottom;">July</span> <span style="font-size: 20px; display:inline-block;vertical-align:bottom;">2016</span>
  <hr style="margin-top: 5px;">
</div>
```